# Universal Link not opens in iOS if www is not there in the link

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

Im implementing the Universal links for iOS. I have stucked at some point where my deeplink is http://www.mydomain.in/path opens my app and proceed to the path when tapped, if www is excluded from the link and tapped, the link lands in safari. Any one know why this is happening and is something to be configured on my server side?

And also continueuser activity delegate is never called when app is in background state.

Comment: I cannot find a reference now, but I remember reading somewhere that Apple treats this as separate paths. In order to handle both, you need two entries in your entitlements - one with `www` and one without.

Comment: @Losiowaty thanks for the quick response, i added both entitlements but the link is not opening my app without 'www' did you ever face this issue? Or else should i redirect to the original URL from this kind of call at my web clicks? ensuring that this the universal link and should do the call it should do.

Answer (score 0):

**`www` is treated at a separate subdomain and needs to be handled by a separately hosted AASA file.** The entitlements file will tell your app what domains should be handled but if no AASA is found for a certain domain that link will not open the app. This means that in addition to adding `www.domain.in` to your entitlements, you also need to ensure that you have another AASA file hosted at `www.domain.in/apple-app-site-association`. This will ensure that your app handles the domain `www.domain.in` and `domain.in`

Comment: @clayjines94 thanks for the quick response, will check this and get back to you. I appreciate it. thanks again.